# error collapse bootstrap in vuejs and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, npm, vue.js

I have a problem when use bootstap. I have master.blade.php contain all source javascript (**including jquery**)

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset("/js/jquery.js")}}"></script>
```

I use npm to build vuejs. In my component contain collapse of bootstrap:

```
<a :href="'#'+item.id" class="list-context" :id="'list-parent-'+item.id"  data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="'#list-sub-'+item.id">
 {{ item.value }}
</a>

<div  :id="'list-sub-'+item.id" class="collapse" :data-parent="'#list-parent-'+item.id">                        
   Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry 
   richardson ad squid.
</div>
```

When i click a tag , it add show class. But i re-click, it change class ,as follows :(remove show class-> add collapsing ->remove collapsing -> app collapse show)
It looks like two jquery file collide, one file inside  master.blade.php, one file include in resources/assets/bootstrap.js. When i remove script tag in  master.blade.php then it work fine

Someone can tell me some suggest for this situations . I want keep script tag in  master.blade.php because i use it for main.js

Comment: What does `changeCate(item.id)` do?

Comment: sorry , it not relate to error